# Reimplement insert iterator to make easy work with "related types" to the one stored on the container

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator

We have the following lightweight classes:

```
struct A {};
struct B { A get_a() const { return /* sth */; } };
```

And let's suppose I have an ordered container of type `A`, and I want to copy objects from another container of type `B` to it:

```
std::copy(b_cont.begin(), b_cont.end(),
          std::make_insert_iterator(a_cont, a_cont.end())
         );
```

Of course, it won't work because `a_cont` and `b_cont` have different types, and classes `A` and `B` don't provide conversion operators. The most obvious solution is to call the function `get_a` for each `B` object on the range `[b_cont.begin(), b_cont.end())`, so, lets write a custom insert iterator:

```
template<template<class...> class container>
struct ba_insert_iterator : public std::insert_iterator<container<A> >
{
    using std::insert_iterator<container<A>>::insert_iterator;

    ba_insert_iterator& operator=(B const& o)
    {
        std::insert_iterator<container<A>>::operator=(o.get_a());

        return *this;
    }
};

template<template<class...> class container>
ba_insert_iterator<container> make_a_inserter(container<A>& c)
{ return ba_insert_iterator<container>(c, c.end()); }
```

Just an iterator that receives an object of type B, instead of another one of type A, and a function to create them easily. But when instantiating the template:

```
std::copy(b_cont.begin(), b_cont.end(), make_a_inserter(a_cont));
```

It says that it doesn't find the `operator=` because the second operand is an `A` object (as expected), but the first operand is an `std::insert_iterator<std::set<A> >`!!, so the compiler is "casting" the iterator to its clase base, which of course lacks of a method for receiving `B` objects to insert.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Why not just use `std::transform` passing a lambda expression calling `B::get_a()` on its argument?

Comment: Because I need an insert_iterator. Transform doesn't work with sets, because it assigns elements by `*__result = __unary_op(*__first)`, and `*__result` is a constant reference when working with sets.

Comment: I was thinking of still using the insert_iterator (or back_insert_iterator) as the output iterator of the `std::transform` call - something like `std::transform(b_cont.begin(), b_cont.end(), std::back_inserter(a_cont), [](const B& b) { return b.get_a(); });`

Comment: It's amazing how many things can be done with the STL. Anyway, the output iterator must be `std::inserter(a_cont, a_cont.end());`, since the `back_inserter` iterator doesn't work with sets either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inherited `operator*` (and `operator++` too, for that matter) from `insert_iterator`.

And those return `insert_iterator&`, not `ba_insert_iterator&`.

For obvious reasons, `std::copy` dereferences the output iterator before assigning to it.